# pod Controller: request did not complete within requested timeout

Tags: kubernetes, controller, kubernetes-statefulset

Scenario:

1. Stop docker and change docker's home directory

2、systemctl daemon-load &&systemctl restart docker

3、kubectl get po |egrep -v "Running|Complate"|awk '{print $1}' |xargs kubectl delete po

It is found that the pod managed by the controller is not recreated

```
$ kubectl get sts |grep consul
consul-master                                   0/3     7d9h
 
$ kubectl describe sts consul
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate     57m (x2 over 7d9h)  statefulset-controller  create Pod consul-master-0 in StatefulSet consul-master successful
  Warning  RecreatingFailedPod  57m                 statefulset-controller  StatefulSet default/consul-master is recreating failed Pod consul-master-0
  Normal   SuccessfulDelete     57m                 statefulset-controller  delete Pod consul-master-0 in StatefulSet consul-master successful
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate     34m                 statefulset-controller  create Pod consul-master-0 in StatefulSet consul-master successful
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate     31m                 statefulset-controller  create Pod consul-master-0 in StatefulSet consul-master successful
  Warning  FailedCreate         24s (x17 over 10m)  statefulset-controller  create Pod consul-master-0 in StatefulSet consul-master failed error: Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout
```

No new pod is generated